# Is it possible to remove the common background from a set of images using Photoshop?

Tags: image-processing, photoshop, image-manipulation, photoshop-script

I know you can remove people, cars, etc in the *foreground* of a stack of photos taken from a set position - essentially only KEEPING the common background. But my problem is the opposite of that...

I have 90 images of football players, all taken from a tripod in a set location. Is it possible to use a stack (or some other method) to process these photos and automatically REMOVE the common background in them - leaving behind layers containing only the players (and whatever other minor background changes there may have been)?

Comment: Yes it's possible, But if you share any sample image here so I can give you a proper answer for this.

Comment: Does Photoshop `Select Subject` give you reasonable results? (you can find it in the top menu of a `magic wand` tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CC2018 Photoshop has a `Select Subject` functionality which isn't *ideal* depending on the subject and background, but may produce decent results and can be automated using this AM command:

```
executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('autoCutout'), undefined, DialogModes.NO);
```

[image]

This might work depending on the files you have.